Trying to map a range of values (positive and negative) to the corresponding values in another range
I'm working on an ASCII based heatmap for the bed mesh of a 3d printer. I have an array of colors (length 107), and the bed mesh can have a wide array of values, which will always include negative and positive values - Example below:
{"mesh_matrix": [
    [ 0.240094, 0.178237, 0.114668, 0.054469, 0.001266, -0.042774, -0.076938, -0.101971, -0.120074, -0.134906, -0.151581, -0.17667, -0.218202 ], 
    [ 0.126341, 0.10407, 0.054248, -0.002618, -0.05146, -0.082652, -0.092006, -0.080773, -0.055648, -0.02876, -0.017682, -0.045426, -0.140442 ], 
    [ 0.12967, 0.115636, 0.068095, 0.010321, -0.040461, -0.073068, -0.082363, -0.069252, -0.040688, -0.009667, 0.00477, -0.022463, -0.122497 ], 
    [ 0.200219, 0.175653, 0.124276, 0.064281, 0.009271, -0.031736, -0.054312, -0.058614, -0.049389, -0.035969, -0.032275, -0.056816, -0.132687 ], 
    [ 0.298821, 0.255262, 0.198163, 0.136783, 0.07823, 0.027458, -0.012731, -0.041688, -0.060917, -0.074073, -0.086965, -0.107555, -0.145957 ], 
    [ 0.396996, 0.334024, 0.272435, 0.211874, 0.152394, 0.094456, 0.038925, -0.012924, -0.059411, -0.098447, -0.127539, -0.143785, -0.143875 ], 
    [ 0.476957, 0.399923, 0.337079, 0.280125, 0.223227, 0.163025, 0.098625, 0.031606, -0.033983, -0.091625, -0.132331, -0.144644, -0.114635 ], 
    [ 0.531606, 0.449362, 0.389391, 0.338633, 0.287678, 0.23076, 0.165761, 0.09421, 0.021282, -0.044201, -0.08977, -0.099308, -0.053054 ], 
    [ 0.564536, 0.487167, 0.43397, 0.391022, 0.348181, 0.299085, 0.24115, 0.175572, 0.107325, 0.045164, 0.001623, -0.006987, 0.039427 ], 
    [ 0.590031, 0.526586, 0.482725, 0.447438, 0.412655, 0.373249, 0.327031, 0.274756, 0.220117, 0.16975, 0.13323, 0.123075, 0.154741 ], 
    [ 0.633064, 0.589288, 0.554874, 0.524556, 0.494505, 0.462327, 0.427067, 0.389203, 0.350654, 0.31477, 0.286343, 0.271598, 0.278198 ], 
    [ 0.7293, 0.705362, 0.676938, 0.645575, 0.61262, 0.579226, 0.546345, 0.514736, 0.484958, 0.457376, 0.432156, 0.409267, 0.388482 ], 
    [ 0.925094, 0.913319, 0.882748, 0.840219, 0.791376, 0.740674, 0.691375, 0.645551, 0.604082, 0.566656, 0.531771, 0.496733, 0.457656 ]
]}

In the above data, the minimum value is -0.218202, and the max value is 0.925094.
So if I have an array of 107 characters, we would map -0.218202 to colors[0] and 0.925094 to colors[-1].
What I tried doing was:

Getting the positive value of the minimum mesh value and using that as an offset for all the values. This would mean I was dealing with a range that was 0 to 1.143296 instead of -0.218202 to 0.925094.
Took the max value of the new range (1.143296) and divided it by the amount of colors in the color array - 107/1.143296 = 93.5890618003
Take that value and multiply it by the offset mesh value, round the result and use that as the index for the color: eg: If the mesh value is 0.496733, then colorIdx = round((0.496733+0.218202)*93.5890618003) = 67


Your input is JSON. As you've tagged bash, you might be looking for a command-line JSON processor. With jq, for example, this could be solved as follows, replicating your steps:
< input.json jq --argjson n 107 '
  ([.[][][]] | [min, $n / (max - min)]) as [$min, $s]
  | .[][][] |= ($s * (. - $min) | round)
'

{
  "mesh_matrix": [
    [
      43,
      37,
      31,
      26,
      21,
      16,
      13,
      11,
      9,
      8,
      6,
      4,
      0
    ],
    [
      32,
      30,
      25,
      20,
      16,
      13,
      12,
      13,
      15,
      18,
      19,
      16,
      7
    ],
    [
      33,
      31,
      27,
      21,
      17,
      14,
      13,
      14,
      17,
      20,
      21,
      18,
      9
    ],
    [
      39,
      37,
      32,
      26,
      21,
      17,
      15,
      15,
      16,
      17,
      17,
      15,
      8
    ],
    [
      48,
      44,
      39,
      33,
      28,
      23,
      19,
      17,
      15,
      13,
      12,
      10,
      7
    ],
    [
      58,
      52,
      46,
      40,
      35,
      29,
      24,
      19,
      15,
      11,
      8,
      7,
      7
    ],
    [
      65,
      58,
      52,
      47,
      41,
      36,
      30,
      23,
      17,
      12,
      8,
      7,
      10
    ],
    [
      70,
      62,
      57,
      52,
      47,
      42,
      36,
      29,
      22,
      16,
      12,
      11,
      15
    ],
    [
      73,
      66,
      61,
      57,
      53,
      48,
      43,
      37,
      30,
      25,
      21,
      20,
      24
    ],
    [
      76,
      70,
      66,
      62,
      59,
      55,
      51,
      46,
      41,
      36,
      33,
      32,
      35
    ],
    [
      80,
      76,
      72,
      70,
      67,
      64,
      60,
      57,
      53,
      50,
      47,
      46,
      46
    ],
    [
      89,
      86,
      84,
      81,
      78,
      75,
      72,
      69,
      66,
      63,
      61,
      59,
      57
    ],
    [
      107,
      106,
      103,
      99,
      94,
      90,
      85,
      81,
      77,
      73,
      70,
      67,
      63
    ]
  ]
}

Demo
